# Unread mail folder count Microsoft Outlook on Android incorrect

Tags: email, outlook

I have an annoying problem with Microsoft Outlook on Android. All my incoming mail is moved to folders by means of rules immediately upon arrival. I have about 50 different folders. Normally, next to each folder should be the number of unread messages. This is almost never true. Sometimes it doesn't update the number until I click on a folder. So for example, there is no number behind a folder name, but when I click on the folder, it appears there are 5 unread messages and then the number 5 is displayed behind the name. And sometimes all the numbers behind the folder name disappeared out of nowhere.

I've done absolutely everything and searched the entire Internet for a solution. I don't come across many threads that have the same problem, but they do exist. Perhaps the problem is with me.

Is there a solution?

Comment: I would assume that the main problem is that IMAP doesn't allow to monitor multiple folders, so you need to check each folder manually respectively wait using IMAP IDLE. As Outlook is a server side mail program this would mean MS would need to maintain a large number of network connection just for you or regularity check all the folders for new messages and then forward the result to your mail client. A local mail client can easily be configured to periodically check a list of mail folders, so may be you use the wrong mail client.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The weird thing is that it does work for some folders. If I would migrate my Outlook e-mail account to a Gmail account, and add the Gmail account to the Outlook Android app. Would the problem still persist? Gmail has no problem with this, but I don't know how it would work if I added it to the Outlook app

Comment: IMHO I would throw away Outlook app. For me it wouldn't be an option giving the Microsoft servers full access to my Email accounts and let them download and process all mails. I prefer traditional mail apps where the app directly talks to the mail server without a MS server in between.

Comment: Thanks again! What are other the traditional mail apps that directly talks to the mail server besides Gmail? Maybe Yahoo? Or AOL? Or maybe a Icloud adres? Would the same problem occur if I would add one of these to my Gmail app?

Comment: As far as I know Gmail directly talks o IMAP servers. You don't need to rely on companies to publish good mail clients. Open source apps like FairEmail or K9 also exist.